# Implementing tabs - will my approach have problems?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

The layout of my page:

```
<div id="header">This is where you select tabs</div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">Main Content</div>
    <div id="right">Sidebar</div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <form>
        <input id="msgForm" type="text" name="chat" size="100"/>
        <input id="enterB" type="submit" value="enter"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

The left and right needs to change content when you select another tab on the header. I am thinking of putting the innerHTML of each tab into an array, and when I want to switch tabs I just `arrayOfContent[currentTabId] = getElementById("left").innerHTML; getElementById("left").innerHTML = arrayOfContent[switchTabId]`

And the same for right. This page will use ajax requests to add divs and remove old divs (which for the current tab I can just remove divs with javascript by id, but for tabs not currently active I'll have to split strings as I'll mark a `<!-- SPLIT ME -->` at the end of every js-created div.)

Will this work? Are there better approaches to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to me,
better approach is to use jquery library and Ui library
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
see the example of ajax page.